Amazon S3 (PHP) Copy files larger than 5GB
I have a PHP file which copies backup files from one folder to another in Amazon S3 at the end of every day. Recently, it stopped working and is generating the following error.
The specified copy source is larger than the maximum allowable size for a cop (truncated...) InvalidRequest (client): The specified copy source is larger than the maximum allowable size for a copy source: 5368709120

After researching the issue I found a backup file that has grown larger than 5GB in size. I believe Amazon S3 requires Multi-part copying for files over that size.
I have been using "copyObject" within a loop that copies each file individually. I think that I now need the script to look at the size of each file and use Multi-part uploading if it finds a file over 5GB. I can't find much documentation of how to achieve Multi-part uploading using PHP.
Here is my current code...
// STEP #1 - SYSTEM FOLDER BACKUP
$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array('Bucket' => 'backups', 'Prefix' => $yesterday_system));
$objects = iterator_to_array($objects);

// Find Count
$count = '0'; foreach ($objects as $object) { $count++; }

// Loop Through Files
if ($count > '0') {

foreach ($objects as $object) {

// Copy Object
$key = rawurlencode($object['Key']);
list($ignore_1a, $ignore_1b, $key_2) = explode('/',$object['Key']);
$date_modified = $object['LastModified'];
$key_3 = $yesterday_year . '/' . $yesterday_month . '/' . $yesterday_day . '/system/' . $key_2;

$s3->copyObject(array(
'ACL' => 'private',
'Bucket' => 'backups',
'CopySource' => "backups/{$key}",
'Key' => "_final/{$key_3}" ));

} }

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Have you tried the MultipartCopy class?

You should consider changing your workflow so that you don't have to copy objects around as you're likely generating a fair bit of needless bandwidth/API fees in doing so. Upload the object to its final destination the first time and move the smarts of "what day is yesterday/today/tomorrow/etc?" somewhere more relevant in the application so you don't need to copy/rename objects. Versioning and lifecycle policies can also save you in the long run as, for example, S3 will handle the logic of deleting old backup files without incurring API usage.

Chris Haas, I have yet to try the MultipartCopy class. Not sure if multi-part works by just changing the code from "$s3->copyObject(array(..." to "$s3->MultipartCopy(array(..."

Sammitch, I am unable to save backups directly to their final destination since they are placed there as a mirror backup through WHM. They are consistently changing based on retention settings.

I don't use S3 for storage, but the docs make it sounds like MultipartCopy does a bunch of magic stuff to automatically split chucks for you. It says it is similar to MultipartUploader which lists part_size in the config with a default value of 5242880, so I think this is what you are looking for.

I just tried MultipartCopy and am getting the follwing error... "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MultipartCopy' not found".  I updated the PHP SDK to the latest version and it still is not finding that class ?

I able to make it work by using the FULL PATH to the MultipartCopy class.  See answer... "$copier = new Aws\S3\MultipartCopy"

Special thanks to Chris Haas for pointing me in the right direction. I needed to use the MultipartCopy class found in the S3 SDK. This is now working...
// STEP # 2 - ACCOUNTS FOLDER BACKUP
$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array('Bucket' => 'backups', 'Prefix' => $yesterday_accounts));
$objects = iterator_to_array($objects);

// Find Count
$count = '0'; foreach ($objects as $object) { $count++; }

// Loop Through Files
if ($count > '0') {
 
foreach ($objects as $object) {

// Get File Information
$key = rawurlencode($object['Key']);
list($ignore_1a, $ignore_1b, $key_2) = explode('/',$object['Key']);
$date_modified = $object['LastModified'];
$key_3 = $yesterday_year . '/' . $yesterday_month . '/' . $yesterday_day . '/accounts/' . $key_2;
$file_size = $object['Size'];

// Over 4.5 GB - Use MultipartCopy
if ($file_size > '4500000000') { 

$copier = new Aws\S3\MultipartCopy($s3, "backups/{$key}", [
'bucket' => 'backups',
'key' => "_final/{$key_3}",
]);

try { $result = $copier->copy(); echo "Copy complete: {$result['ObjectURL']}\n"; }
catch (MultipartUploadException $e) { echo $e->getMessage() . "\n"; }
}

// Under 4.5 GB - Use CopyObject
else {
  
$s3->copyObject(array(
'ACL' => 'private',
'Bucket' => 'backups',
'CopySource' => "backups/{$key}",
'Key' => "_final/{$key_3}" ));

}

} }

